# Final comma in regex

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex which only allows me to put two numbers followed by two decimal places.

The problem is that, right now, it lets me put, for example, `33,`
how do I avoid it?

My regex:

```
"^[0-9]{0,2}+([,][0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

I want it to accept `33,00`, `3,3` or `33,3` and not accept `33,` `333,22` or `3,44444`.

Comment: Change the (last) `{0,2}` to `{1,2}`?

Comment: (OT: There’s no need to put `,` in `[]` like that.)

Comment: btw, your regex as it currently is, will also accept `,` which is obviously not a valid number. But also `,1`, which I'mt not sure whether it's intended or not ...

Comment: Would you need to accept `33`? without any comma?

Comment: Maybe `^\d{0,2}+(,\d\d?)?$` but should `,00` match?

Comment: `^\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2})$` - Should work. Demo link - https://regex101.com/r/yAIZdT/1

Answer (score 0):

This [*seems*](https://regex101.com/r/n29EHP/1) to do what you're asking for

```
[\D^]\d\d?(\,\d{1,2})$
```

Start with either a non-digit or the beginning of the line

Match one or 2 digits

Then a comma plus 1-2 digits (but no more)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your pattern is optional due to the zero in the quantifier `{0,2}` and the optional group `(...)?`

Therefore is could possibly also match an empty string or a mere `,` or in your case `33,`

Also note that you can just write `,` instead of `[,]` and this notation with the added plus sign `{0,2}+` means a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

For the example data, you can write the pattern as:

```
^[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{1,2}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CAcFpf/1).

Answer (score -4):

***EDIT:***
My mistake, I read the question again and fixed my answer.

```
\b[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{1,2}\b
```

**Explaination**

```
\b          Word boundary
[0-9]{1,2}  1 to 2 Digits of 0-9
,           Comma
[0-9]{1,2}  1 to 2 Digits of 0-9
\b          Word boundary
```

For testing i recommend
https://ihateregex.io/
https://regex101.com/

Comment: It will also accept `33,x`.

Comment: `[^$]` matches any one char that is not a `$` char.

Comment: What is `{1}` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Hm, how would that accept `3,3` if you need two digits before the comma. And if you input `12,34` it won't include the `4` in the match. You should have followed your own recommendation and tested your regex at one of the mentioned sites before posting it here

Comment: @Biffen it's (as regex101.com calls it) a "*meaningless quantifier*"